# How to prevent extra blank pages in an rdl report file?

Tags: vb.net-2010

In my design view my report fits to one page, but when I print and export the file it creates extra blank pages displaying the header and footer. How can I fix this?

Comment: Without the report it's a little difficult. Maybe some blank space wrap to the second page?

Answer (score 4):

The last time I encountered this issue, it was caused by an element in the header which extended further than the page width.

Check your header/footer to make sure that nothing is wider than your page width and check that there are no elements which extend into the left or right margin.

Comment: I had extra space on the page, thanks Victor, what a silly easy fix!